# LINQ Select into Dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I'm trying to take a `Select` and project each elements into a `Dictionary<string, UdpReceiveResult>`
I currently have a `Select` that just projects the value of a `Dictionary` to a list `tasks` of type `UdpReceiveResult`. `clients` is a dictionary of type `Dictionary<string, UdpClient>`. I have

```
var tasks = clients.Select(c => c.Value.ReceiveAsync()).OrderByCompletion();
```

I want to project the key and `ReceiveAsync()` result into a new `Dictionary`. The `OrderByCompletion` is from Nito.AsyncEx dll.

Comment: .ToDictionary(x=>x.[key], x=>x.[value]) is a linq function is this not correct, or are you needing an async lambda expression?

Comment: .ToDictionary(x=>x.[key], x=>x.[value])  only allows you to populate with values from type Task<UdpReceiveResult>. The key is from clients which is a dictionary of type string,UdpClient

Comment: It does not have to be a select statement. I really just need a way to run the ReceiveAsync()).OrderByCompletion() on each UdpClient and project into a Dictionary<string, UdpReceiveResult>.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Well, for starters, you'll need your result to also include the key:

```
var tasks = clients.Select(async c => new
{
    c.Key,
    Value = await c.Value.ReceiveAsync(),
});
```

Then when the tasks finish you can put them in a dictionary:

```
var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
var dictionary = results.ToDictionary(
    pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
```

Answer (score 52):

This code would accomplish the same in one line of code.

```
var tasks = clients.ToDictionary(c => c.Key, c => c.Value.ReceiveAsync());
```